# RobotFramework: How to print messages from python library's __init__ function in the log file?

Tags: robotframework

I am using a custom Python library in the RobotFramework. I have included several helpful debug messages in the `__init__` method of the Python library class (e.g. the `__init__` is loading a *config.ini* file and creating a pool of SSH connections based on the hosts included in the *config.ini* file). The messages are included using RobotFramework logger.

The object state is then used for calling the subsequent keywords.

Unfortunately, the log.html generated by the RobotFramework doesn't include the above messages. It only shows the subsequent messages resulting from calling the keywords.

How can we make the `__init__` debug messages appear in the RobotFramework log file?

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is to save that data into a class variable during init and create a keyword that logs all that info and run it in suite setup.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. However, your suggested approach won't work if one of the SSH target host is down or unreachable. There is an exception thrown during the connect() call (made during `__init__`) and all I get is a stack trace of exception at the top in the log and "unable to import library" error under the suite/test case. Looks like I will have to open a local file and write to it till `__init__` is complete.

Comment: If you increase the log level from debug to warn or error, messages will show on top of the log. Also, you could wrap ssh open inside try-except and then log and fail gracefully to avoid stack traces.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. Implemented your suggestion (wrapping ssh open) and it is working fine now. Showing all messages in the log.html

Comment: @AmitTendulkar, could you provide more details with above example modified, how you solved the issue? I am facing the same problem. One of my libraries are malfunctioning, but the log statement are not of any help for troubleshooting

Comment: @Patz, refer to the messages from @Pekka. Instead of using Robot logger in `__init__` use an internal/private function that will accumulate messages say in a member variable (list). Write a keyword that will iterate through the list and call Robot's logger to log the messages. Call the above keyword in your top level suite setup. To save you from exceptions in `__init__`, use try/except blocks.